# Intersection of a Generalized Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a sequence of sets, where each set $ x_i = [2, 3 + \frac{1}{i})$, where i starts from 1, up to infinity, what is the generalized intersection of all such sets $ x_i $.

My intuition tells me that the answer is $[2, 3]$, where the upper bound should be 3(inclusive), because $ 3<3 + \frac{1}{i} $ for all values of i, and $ 2<3<3 + \frac{1}{i} $, which show that 3 should be included in the interval.

However, ChatGPT outputs the answer $[2, 3)$, where 3 is exclusive for the upper bound of the interval.

Can someone explain what the real answer is and why it is that answer?

Comment: Your answer and intuition are correct. ChatGPT isn't.

Comment: chatGPT is artificial, but not intelligent. Its outputs are based on which word/symbol is most likely to follow the previous symbols, on the basis of the corpus it has been fed. It is a stochastic parrot, regurgitating text but with no knowledge or concern for meaning, and expecting it to reason or "understand" is to expect magic. Asking it for mathematical answers is an exercise in NS, not AI. (natural st*p*dity).